# "List index out of range" error when trying to navigate a 2D array acting as a matrix. Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D array that acts as a 8x8 matrix.
My goal is to make this matrix fully navigable using a cursor that is moved by wasd.
This works, but only for up and left. Not for down and right.

-Code to create the matrix

```
matrix = []
for i in range(8):
    i = []
    for j in range(8):
        i.append(" ")
    matrix.append(i)
```

-Code to navigate the matrix, this works by finding the coordinates for the cursor (+), then deleting its old place and inserting it in the new set of coordinates.

```
row= len(matrix)
column=len(matrix[0])
direction = input("wasd")
        if direction == "w":
            for i in range(row):
                for j in range(column):
                    if matrix[i][j]=="+":
                        matrix[i][j]=" "
                        matrix[i-1][j]= "+"
        elif direction == "a":
            for i in range(row):
                for j in range(column):
                    if matrix[i][j]=="+":
                        matrix[i][j]=" "
                        matrix[i][j-1]= "+"
        elif direction == "s":
            for i in range(row):
                for j in range(column):
                    if matrix[i][j]=="+":
                        matrix[i][j]=" "
                        matrix[i+1][j]= "+"
        elif direction == "d":
            for i in range(row):
                for j in range(column):
                    if matrix[i][j]=="+":
                        matrix[i][j]=" "
                        matrix{i][j+1]= "+"
```

I get a ***list index out of range*** error when i try to move down or right, but up and left work perfectly.

Comment: Looks like this is not all the code that you have.
Can you describe explicitly the running proccess giving you an error and give us a copy of the traceback?
But for now, I am almost sure that you should checking collisions with borders before moving your cursor.
For example, if matricx[3][7] == '+' and you type 'd' 
the last line of your code will be equal to matrix[3][8] = '+'
there is no such element in your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your logic works like this: when you are on the first row - clicking up takes you to the last row and when you are on the first column  - clicking left takes you to the last column.

Your up and left works because in python, if you access an element in an array as follows:
arr[-1] - it will give you the last element of the array.

so in your example - if i = 0, matrix[i-1][j] = matrix[-1][j] => this will give you last row jth column data.

But for your down/right logic - when you are on the last row/column you increment the row/column by 1 which does not exist in your matrix. You have to come back to the first row/column.

try to use the % (modulo) operator - matrix[(i+1)%row][j] (for rows) / matrix[i][(j+1)%row] (for columns)